# not getting updated value from child state , angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have two states with same controller as below:

```
.state('parent',{
 abstract: true,
 url: '/parent',
 templateUrl: 'mytemplate.html'
 controller: 'mycontroller'
})
.state('parent.child',{
 url: '/child',
 templateUrl: 'mytemplate2.html',
 controller: 'mycontroller'
})
```

And the controller is:

```
.controller('mycontroller', ['$scope', function($scope){
 $scope.x = 'user';
 $scope.check = function(){
   alert($scope.x);
 }
 $scope.checkFromParent = function(){
  alert($scope.x);
 }
}]
```

Now in `mytemplate2.html` I'm changing the value of variable `x` to `buyer`. And then I press a button which calls the function `check()` which produces a alert in which value of `x` is shown correctly as `buyer`.

But after changing the value of `x` to `buyer` in `mytemplate2.html` if I press a button from inside of `mytemplate.html` which calls function `checkFromParent()` the the alert shows value of `x` as `user`. Why?

Maybe I'm missing something very basic here but after updating the value of `x` it is shown as different by calling both functions. How can I get it work in my desired way? Although I can get it done by using Service but i think there should be some more ways to get it done.

`mytemplate.html` is shown on left half of screen and `mytemplate2.html` is shown on right of of screen using `ui-view`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> They each have their own instance of the controller, thus the data is
>   different in both

To make it work, you should use `service` to share data between them.

May this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/danielclasen/m729ru7w/) may give you some ideas.

Comment: thanks, I get it now. I can do it using service but i'm wondering if there are alternate ways.

Comment: I am not sure if there is any other alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same controller for both the html template but the scope of both controller are different that's why you are seeing so.